# Method to get a value from plist

Tags: ios, properties, cocos2d-iphone, plist

I have a integer called NumberX and a plist called PlistX.

**Example**

```
int NumberX;
```

PlistX:

[image: plist]

I was wondering how I'd make NumberX = value of Three

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PlistX" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
int number = [[[[dict objectForKey:@"One"] objectForKey:@"Two"]objectForKey:@"Three"] intValue];
NSLog(@"%d",number);
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Get data (i.e. `NSMutableDictionary *`) from plist saved to disk:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary =  [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainers format:NULL errorDescription:&error];
```

2) Retrieve needed object from dictionary.

```
//in your case
NSNumber *tmpNumber = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"One"] objectForKey:@"Two"] objectForKey:@"Three"];
// convert to int
int NumberX = [tmpNumber intValue];
```